# Intercepting dependencies in MEF

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef

Is it possible to intercept dependency requests in MEF before they get handled by MEF?

This would be useful for implementing decorators and advanced lifetime management.

Something like...

```
catalogue.AddInterceptor<IExpensiveService>(b => ... return from pool ...);
```

Or even...

```
catalogue.AddInterceptor<IExpensiveService>(b => new Decorator(b()));
```

(where 'b' is the underlying MEF resolution func for resolving the service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box, but you can write your own [ExportProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.exportprovider.aspx) or [ComposablePartCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepartcatalog.aspx) implementation to do this.

[MefContrib](https://github.com/mefcontrib) appears to have implemented something like that, take a look at  [InterceptingCatalog](https://github.com/MefContrib/MefContrib/blob/master/src/MefContrib/Hosting/Interception/InterceptingCatalog.cs). See also this (possibly outdated) [blog post](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2010/11/introduction-to-interceptingcatalog.html) about it.